# How to fetch the data from firestore and list out it in dropdown in textinput for picking in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

how can I implement dropdown suggestions... from the firestore database for any field or any collection in TEXTINPUT and listing out for picking it...

Comment: Please let me know if the below information was useful, or you are looking for some other information.

Answer (score 0):

The approach here would be to fetch data from Firestore and map it to a List. There are many ways to fetch data from Firestore, check [Retrieving Data List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists). Once you've done that, the data can be displayed in the form dropdown list using various methods.

Here are a few examples of similar implementations that you are trying to implement.

[2][Load values for a dropdown menu from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971199/load-values-for-a-dropdown-menu-from-firebase)
[3][Populate react select options array with key value pairs from firebase collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987388/populate-react-select-options-array-with-key-value-pairs-from-firebase-collectio)
[4][How to display data from a firebase firestore in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64469931/how-to-display-data-from-a-firebase-firestore-in-react-native)
[5][Get List of keys from Firbase database and load to dropdown list in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152226/get-list-of-keys-from-firbase-database-and-load-to-dropdown-list-in-reactjs)